# is there any way to turn a multidimensional array into a single dimension one in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to turn a multidimensional array into a single dimension one. For example:

```
arr1=([[1,4],[3,7]])
```

and transform it to:

```
arr=([1,4,3,7])
```

is it possible to get this with a unique command in python?

Thanks and I appreciate very much your advice

Comment: Search "flatten numpy array"

Comment: @leaf Wrong programming language. :)

Comment: Just do `sum(arr, [])`

Comment: check [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) documentation

Comment: @Tagc Ok. Thanks for the heads up.